# How to unstacked yticklabel in matplotlib.pcolor

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

The following code is the minimum amount of code needed for reproducing the my heat map problem (full code in comments):

```
import numpy as np
import string
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

def random_letter(chars=string.ascii_uppercase, size=2):
    char_arr = np.array(list(chars))
    if size > 27:
        size = 27
    np.random.shuffle(char_arr)
    return char_arr[:size]

y_labels = [', '.join(x for x in random_letter()) for _ in range(174)]
fig.set_size_inches(11.7, 16.5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.random.poisson(1, (174, 40))
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, 
                    cmap=plt.cm.Blues, 
                    vmin=data.min(), 
                    vmax=data.max(), 
                    edgecolors='white')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+.5, minor=False);
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+.5, minor=False);
ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(40), 
                   minor=False, 
                   rotation=90, 
                   fontsize='x-small', 
                   weight='bold');
ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels, 
                   minor=False,  
                   fontsize='x-small',
                   weight='bold');
cb = fig.colorbar(heatmap, shrink=0.33, aspect=10)
```

My question is: Is there a way of  increase the distance between the y tick labels? When I print this in A3 (good size) it still almost unreadable because the letters are stacking in each other. I'd tried to fix the yticklabelpads without success.

Thank you all in advance
[image: heatmap]

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code you are showing to the _minimum_ that will reproduce the problem.  I suspect that the issue is in the details here, but please make it easier on the people who want to help by reducing the amount of code they need to wade through.

Comment: Done, full code here: https://gist.github.com/tbrittoborges/d4db3f1bb741781d06a0

Comment: by 'unstack' I assume you mean to stagger the labels horizontally?  As you are using tex rendering of the labels try tacking things tex understands as non-breaking white space onto ever-other label.

Comment: By unstack I mean increase the distance between the y tick labels.

Comment: make the font size smaller (you can pass in ints).

Comment: Yes, I know, but doing this (or increasing the heatmap height are not an option. I would rather expand the space in between each cell in the map, however I dont know who to do that.

Comment: Increasing the space between the boxes exactly the same thing as increasing the height of the heatmap.  The only thing that matters here in the pitch of the rows (total height / num_rows).